# how to read a specific xml element in windows 8 platform

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml file of this type

```
<HolyQuran TranslationID="103" Writer="Maulana Mohammad Ali" Language="English" LanguageIsoCode="eng" Direction="ltr">
<Chapter ChapterID="1" ChapterName="The Opening">
    <Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[In the name of Allah, the Beneficent, the Merciful.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[Praise be to Allah, the Lord of the worlds,]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="3"><![CDATA[The Beneficent, the Merciful,]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="4"><![CDATA[Master of the day of Requital.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="5"><![CDATA[Thee do we serve and Thee do we beseech for help.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="6"><![CDATA[Guide us on the right path,]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="7"><![CDATA[The path of those upon whom Thou has bestowed favours, Not those upon whom wrath is brought down, nor those who go astray.]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
```

what I want is to read a specific Verse Cdata section. For example if I pass Chapter id and Verse id to a function so it must return the specific cdata content

i tried this block of code

```
 public  string  getTranslation(int p1, int p2)
    {
        string translationPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Data/eglish-translation.xml");
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(translationPath);
       var  value = (from r in document.Descendants("Chapter").Where
                                  (r => ((int)r.Attribute("ChapterID") == p1)&&(int)r.Attribute("VerseId") == p2))
                 select r.Element("Verse").Value).FirstOrDefault();


          return value;  
    }
```

But its returning null what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

`VerseId` is attribute of `Verse` element, not of `Chapter` element. Here is correct query:

```
var value = (from c in document.Descendants("Chapter")
             where (int)c.Attribute("ChapterID") == p1 
             from v in c.Elements("Verse")
             where (int)v.Attribute("VerseID") == p2
             select (string)v).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or with lambda syntax:

```
var value = document.Descendants("Chapter")
                    .Where(c => (int)c.Attribute("ChapterID") == p1)
                    .SelectMany(c => c.Elements("Verse"))
                    .Where(v => (int)v.Attribute("VerseID") == p2)
                    .Select(v => (string)v)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Side note - if `HolyQuran` is root element of your xml file, then it's better to query for chapters as `document.Root.Elements()` or `document.Root.Elements("Chapter")` to avoid traversing whole tree for descendants.

You also can use xpath:

```
var xpath = 
   String.Format("//Chapter[@ChapterID='{0}']/Verse[@VerseID='{1}']", p1, p2);
var value = (string)document.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
```

Comment: actually I am maping it against another xml file in which i have read Holy Quran in arabic and have loaded data but when I integrate this code and use the return value to be used in sample item template everthing just disappears not even other file which works fine without it

Comment: @user3149814 code above works with xml you have provided

Comment: thanx alot it's working now a bit slow but working thank you again

Comment: @user3149814 make sure you replaced `Descendants("Chapter")` with `Root.Elements("Chapter")`. If xml file is huge and performance is issue then consider to use XmlReader instead of of Linq to XML